# Count number of rows of files matching pattern

Tags: command-line, find, wc

I would like to list the files matching a specific pattern along with their number of rows.
So far I have tried the following, which list me the files matching the desired pattern:

```
find 2021.12.*/ -maxdepth 2 -name "myfilepattern.csv" -ls

123456789  32116 -rw-rw-r--   1 user1 user1 32881884 Dec  1 23:59 2021.12.01/myfilepattern.csv
234567891      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 user1 user1      144 Dec  2 00:00 2021.12.02/myfilepattern.csv
```

I would like to add a column to this result containing the number of rows of each files `2021.12.01/myfilepattern.csv` and `2021.12.02/myfilepattern.csv`.

I don't have any specific requirements about the position of such column. Can be at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: Where do you want the column placed? Could you [edit] your question and provide a formatted example of how you would like the output to appear.

Comment: @Greenonline Anywhere! I would just like to see the column appear somewhere, no matter if it's the first or the last column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-printf` and `-exec` actions, along with `wc -l` to count lines/rows:

`find 2021.12.*/ -maxdepth 2 -name "myfilepattern.csv" -printf '%i\t%k\t%M\t%n\t%u\t%g\t%s\t%Tb %Td %TH:%TM\t' -exec wc -l {} \;`

The row count will be the second to last column.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, it works! Do you know where I can find some explanations about those `%k`, `%M`, etc... to be able to remove the columns that are not relevant for me? Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it works @JejeBelfort. You can find the explanations for those directives in the `find` [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/find.1#ACTIONS) under the `-printf format` action.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly an easy way is to just call `wc -l` on each file and then combine that output with the output from the `-ls` predicate.  The following does that using `paste`, and since I call `wc` before using `-ls`, the `wc` output will be in the first column:

```bsh
find 2021.12.*/ -maxdepth 2 -name 'myfilepattern.csv' \
    -exec wc -l {} \; \
    -ls |
paste - -
```

To avoid getting the pathname of the file in the output of `wc`, you will have to redirect the file into `wc` rather than passing it on the utility's command line.  To do that with `-exec` in `find`, we need to call a shell:

```bsh
find 2021.12.*/ -maxdepth 2 -name 'myfilepattern.csv' \
    -exec sh -c 'wc -l <"$1"' sh {} \; \
    -ls |
paste - -
```

Swap the `-exec` and the `-ls` around if you want to get the number of lines at the end of the `-ls` output.